# .NETCore 3.1 - Error MC1000 Unknown build error, 'Could not find assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Using Visual Studio 16.6, migrating WPF app to target .netcore3.1(.300). Cannot compile with error below:

Error MC1000 Unknown build error, 'Could not find assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Either explicitly load this assembly using a method such as LoadFromAssemblyPath() or use a MetadataAssemblyResolver that returns a valid assembly.'    MyApp C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets 225

I don't seem to have any need or reference for System.Web

I see similar things here but am on current versions:
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2648

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? -> https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3075

Comment: Are you directly referencing System.Web in your WPF app? Then you should remove this dependency before migrating.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be an issue with the structure of the project file. I don't reference System.Web but a third party DevExpress component does.

When you target .netcoreapp31 AND net472, the Nuget packages do not seem to get pointed to the target frameworks correctly. The project file needed to be manually restructured to point them to the correct frameworks.

Details here:
[Issue on github dotnet/wpf](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3064#event-3403349265)